# Looking for a movie where everybody has false memories. Possibly Dark City

Tags: story-identification, dark-city

There's a movie or TV show that I saw 10-20 years ago, modern, where people have fake memories. In one of the scenes, one person (somehow I keep thinking of [Steve Buscemi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Buscemi), but it was someone who had a funny way of talking or an accent or a lisp or something) is challenging another to try to remember something and the person starts reciting their biography. The first person says no, that's a list of facts. Do you remember what your mother's face looks like? When's the last time you saw a movie or went for a walk in the park? When's the last time you had a good steak?

I don't remember much about it, but I remember that scene and in particular the line asking about the steak.

I thought it was Dark City this whole time, but I've just watched it and that's not it. There are certainly plenty of scenes where people challenge one another on their memories, but the line about the steak was never uttered. Although the version that I just watched had little bits and pieces I don't remember seeing, so is it possible that it's an alternate edit than the one I remember?

Comment: There were a couple different cuts of *Dark City*, and honestly the lisp makes me think that's it (Keifer stands out in that movie) but I don't remember those quotes in that movie either (the crazy cop might come close?).

Comment: There's a similar scene in Star Trek - "TNG: Birthright"; **KAHLESS:** *Long ago, a storm was heading toward the city of Quin'lat. The people sought protection within the walls. All except one man who remained outside....* **GOWRON:** *What was his name?* 
**KAHLESS:** *What?*
**GOWRON:** *If you were really there, you should be able to tell us the name of the man outside the walls. Describe him to us. What was he wearing? How tall was he? What colour were his eyes?*

Comment: And from Ghost in the Shell: *And what would l ask a guy who doesn't even know his own name?! Your mother's face. The place you grew up in. Memories of your childhood. Can you remember any of those things? There's nothing sadder than a puppet without a ghost.*

Comment: @Radhil I wasn't aware of different cuts, but I would have sworn that it was Dark City. But I don't know if it's a cut of Dark City or just my memory merging the two, so I'm a little hesitant about the lisp.

Comment: Maybe you're mixing it with a similar scene from [*Bladerunner?*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NwJEb3vJvWY)

Comment: @JoeL. I don't remember that line in particular. You're thinking the scene where Decker convinces whatshername that she is a replicant? Dig up the bit and I will check it out. But I don't seem to remember anything quite like that.

Comment: http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=3551125

Comment: In an early scene in Bladerunner (before we even meet Deckard), a Replicant is found out when he's asked to picture his mother's face and there's no emotional reaction.

Comment: @NikolaiDante thanks for that. I read it through thoroughly and it doesn't appear to mention the line. However, I have apparently always been watching the theatrical cut and just watched the DC without realizing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an animated *Batman* story, "His Silicon Soul", first broadcast in 1992.  Per the quotations from [the episode guide at The World's Finest](http://worldsfinestonline.com/WF/batman/btas/episodes/hissiliconsoul/):

> **ROSSUM:** You don't understand. You're not a man's mind in a robot's body. You're a robot. Period.
>
> **BAT-DUPLICANT:** You're lying! It's not possible! I know my family and friends! I remember names, faces, birthdays! I have memories! A past!
>
> **ROSSUM:** You have information. Data. Nothing more. Do you remember your first kiss? Your favorite song? The last time you tasted a really good steak?
>
> **BAT-DUPLICANT:** No, but—
>
> **ROSSUM:** Can you remember anything beyond cold, hard facts? Facts can be implanted, accessed from any number of sources.

## Further reading

- Steven Padnick (2013-05-14). ["His Silicon Soul" & "Fire from Olympus"](http://tor.com/2013/05/14/batman-animated-series-rewatch-his-silicon-soul-fire-from-olympus/). *Batman: The Animated Series Rewatch*.  Tor.
- "[His Silicon Soul](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/His_Silicon_Soul)".  *DC Animated Universe* Wikia.

Comment: ::slow clap:: Well done. Well done indeed.